# Laravel assigning single route with varying sized slugs

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Im in need of a way of creating a route that would allow a variable amount of slugs, so I dont need to create 10+ routes to that same controller method. This should allow the site admin to create a folder style structure of catagory pages and content without giving a limit.

Then the route would except any of these and pass array of slugs to the contorller:

- www.site/designs/paint/
- www.site/designs/paint/pointalism/
- www.site/designs/paint/pointalism/portrait

How Can I achive this without using get params?

**Current Routes:**

```
 Route::get('/designs/{catagory1}', 'DesignController@catagories')->name('design.items');
 Route::get('/designs/{catagory1}/{catagory2}', 'DesignController@catagories')->name('design.items');
 Route::get('/designs/{catagory1}/{catagory2}/{catagory3}', 'DesignController@catagories')->name('design.items');
 Route::get('/designs/{catagory1}/{catagory2}/{catagory3}/{catagory4}', 'DesignController@catagories')->name('design.items');
 Route::get('/designs/{catagory1}/{catagory2}/{catagory3}/{catagory4}/{catagory5}','DesignController@catagories')->name('design.items');
 ..etc
```

**Desired Routes:**

```
 Route::get('/designs/{catagories}', 'DesignController@catagories')->name('design.items');
```

Answer (score 0):

To tell Laravel, to give the full params to the controller, you have to add a [where clause](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) like this:

```
Route::get('designs/{query}', 'DesignController@catagories')->where('query','.+')
```

Basically what it does, is to match `.+` for the `{query}`, in this case, it will just match anything.

You can then use `explode('/', $theUrlParam)` in your code, to receive all parts in an array.